# Populate existing excel template containing columns from a table in SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

My C# project requires excel report generation. I have an existing excel template which contains columns whose values is to be populated from SQL Server table and certain fields(e.g TestCasePassed, TestCaseFailed etc.)in that excel template which is to be populated with values from code.

i.e. Excel template format

TestCasePassed:     TestCaseFailed:

Date:

Name  Designation   Salary  TestStatus

I require the C# code for this process. Thanks in advance.

I am actually new to C# and I don't have much idea about how to proceed but yes I have to do it using Microsoft.Interop.

Comment: show some efforts what you have tried

Comment: hii...I am actually new to C# and I don't have much idea about how to proceed but yes I have to do it using Microsoft.Interop.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be 100s of way of doing this and, without you being more specific, the question may be more opinion based than anythign else.

If I had this task (and assuming there are a reasonably small number of records) with an existing db I'd just do

1. [Entity Framework db first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj206878.aspx) to the existing sql database
2. Get the entries from the DB
3. Write to the spreadsheet using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

I therefore might end up with code something like this:

```
List<Entry> FromDb()
{
    List<Entry> res;
    using (var dbContext = new MyEntities()
    {
        res = dbContext.Where(e=>MeetsMyFilterCriteria(e)).ToList()
    }
    return res;
}

Main()
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("path/to/excelTemplateFile.xlsx");

    using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["MyWorksheenName"];
        BaseRange startRange = sheet.Range["A2"] //or wherever data is to go
        int offset=0;
        foreach (entry in FromDb())
        {
            startRange.Offset(offset,0).Value = entry.PropertyA;
            startRange.Offset(offset,1).Value = entry.PropertyB;
            startRange.Offset(offset,2).Value = entry.PropertyC;

            // and so on ...

            offset++;
        }

        excelPackage.SaveAs("path/to/excelOutput.xls");

    }
}
```

This approach is nice and easy to implement but would not scale nicely to 1000s of exports of hundreds of thousands of rows but provided we are talking small numbers of rows and relativaly few export the poor performance is negligible and offset by the ease of implementation.

Comment: Thanks Stewart. I am actually new to C# and I don't have much idea about how to proceed but yes I have to do it using Microsoft.Interop. Can you please tell me how to do it using Microsoft.Interop so that beginners like me can be greatly benefited ?

Comment: Ime Microsoft interop is much trickier to use if you don't need to. I'd strongly recommend using something like epplus instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyXLS Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com). Create a query from SQL Server table and populate a DataSet. Load the existing Excel template and insert the DataSet into the sheet.

```
//Load Excel template
ExcelDocument template = new ExcelDocument();
template.easy_LoadXLSXFile("template.xlsx");//or easyLoadXLSFile for xls file (xltx/xlt)

//Get the sheet from the Excel file
ExcelWorksheet sheet = (ExcelWorksheet)template.easy_getSheetAt(0);

//Populate the sheet with SQL table values
sheet.easy_insertDataset(dataSet, false);
```

For more details about how to populate the DataSet or how to format the cells, take a look on more code samples about [how to export DataSet to Excel](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-dataset-to-excel.html).

Comment: Thanks Alex. I am actually new to C# and I don't have much idea about how to proceed but yes I have to do it using Microsoft.Interop. Can you please tell me how to do it using Microsoft.Interop so that beginners like me can be greatly benefited ?